# printf variable placeholder? Is it even a thing?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
char pos[] = {34,92,48,51,51,91,57,59,57,72,37,115,34}; // "\033[9;9H%s"

main() {
    printf(pos,"Aaaaaaa");              // (1) This doesnt work as intended
    printf("\033[9;9H%s","Aaaaaaa");    // (2) Works as intended
}
```

So why (2) works and (1) doesn't?

Comment: Because they're not the same.

Comment: `printf` expects a null terminated string as the format. Is `pos` null terminated? Additionally, the first and last items in `pos` are a quotation mark. Keep in mind that `\0` is the escape sequence for null. You probably want \\0 in your string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with `pos`.

First what you have is a character array, not a null terminated string.  You need to add a 0 to the end of that array.

Second, you don't have the same characters.  In the string literal `"\033[9;9H%s"` there are a total of 8 characters while `pos` has 13.

The sequence `\033` represent a single character whose value is 33 octal or 27 decimal.  You instead have the literal characters `'\'`, `'0'`, `'3'`, and `'3'`.  So replace 92,48,51,51 with 27.  Also, you have 34 for the first and last characters in `pos`, which is the double quote character `"`.  These characters are not part of the string literal but are used to denote it in code.  So get rid of those.

`pos` should now look like this:

```
char pos[] = {27,91,57,59,57,72,37,115,0};
```

Comment: Tx, dbush. No 34 needed. Also seems to work without tracing 0.

Comment: Leave the trailing \0 in there-it might work without it, but it’s not guaranteed.

Comment: @yummyduck "seems to work" is the first step on the road to undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You've got three differences:

1. You don't need the initial and final `34` character (`"`), since string (2) doesn't print them out.
2. You need a null terminator to ensure that you print only your string and nothing more.
3. If `\033` is meant to be an escape character, then its value is just `27`, not `92,48,51,51`.

After addressing those differences, your `pos` array:

```
{34,92,48,51,51,91,57,59,57,72,37,115,34}
```

Should instead look like this (aligned to match the original array):

```
            {27,91,57,59,57,72,37,115,0}
```